# Getting BLE peripherals to communicate with each other

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm wanting to know if what I want to do is even possible and if there is a good practise that I should follow.

For my experiment I have a collection bluetooth low energy beacons laid on the ground with each projecting out their own BLE signal. Each of these signals is getting read in by a fourth device that takes the corresponding RSSI value and uses it to determine it's position within the area.

Following this I now want each of my beacons that are laid on the ground to know the distances that separate them from each other. So my questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible to have the beacons on the ground broadcast different signals using two different UUID values?
2. Can a beacons both read and broadcast a signal at the same time? By that I mean the beacons will still be sending out their initial signal being read in by my fourth device whilst also reading in the distance value from their fellow broadcasting beacons on the ground.

I'm not sure if I've done a good job at describing what it is I'm wanting so I've (terribly) drew a picture in order to show what I want do and describe what I've got so far.
[image]

Key:

- Black dots are my beacons on the floor
- Green dot is my reader that finds its distance from the floor beacons. On the green dot is another app that is projecting out a BLE signal which the floor beacons are reading.
- Purple line is the BLE signal being sent out from my reader device.
- Yellow line is the RSSI value showing the beacons distance from the BLE signal being projected
- Blue line (this is the key to this post) is meant to represent the beacons projecting and reading their own BLE signal so they can find their distance from each other.
- Green line is then each beacon sending its distance from the other beacons to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

At this point Bluetooth Smart-only devices currently do not support simultaneous peripheral/central mode.

What I would suggest is using the nRF51922 which supports concurrent BLE/ANT.

ANT is fully capable of doing this functionality for you as it supports all kinds of topologies, and you can relay your final information over BLE, or go with an nRF51422 and stay ANT only, I believe all latest Sony and Samsung devices support ANT anyway so it might be enough for you.

You can read more about it at http://www.thisisant.com